# HTTP Error running on a device "Unknown Error" Angular

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic3, httpclient, http-error

I'm having a problem that I can't solve it. I'm working in an Ionic + angular App that makes requests using HTTPClient. Running it with 'ionic serve' command works fine and the request are made it successfully, but when I want to running it using an emulator, it gives me this error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
HttpErrorResponseerror: ProgressEventheaders: HttpHeadersmessage: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: null__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

I've read that maybe something related to CORS was happened but, I set headers for that and nothings happens.

Here is my interceptor's code which was executed every time a request was made

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInjectableHeader implements HttpInterceptor {

  private authService: UserData;

  constructor(private injector: Injector){}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.authService = this.injector.get(UserData); // get it here within intercept
    if (req.params.has('noAuth')){
      const modified = req.clone({setHeaders: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type,Accept, X-Auth-Token ,App-Auth,X-XSRF-TOKEN,Authorization'
        }});
      return next.handle(modified);
    }
    else{
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.authService.getAccessToken())
        .switchMap(token => {
          const modified = req.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization:  `Bearer ${token}`,'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}});
          console.log(req);
          return next.handle(modified);
        });
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the output of 'ionic info' command

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v6.12.3
    npm  : 5.6.0 
    OS   : macOS High Sierra

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

On my server side I have this config

```
# NelmioCors Configuration
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
        '^/oauth/v2/token':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```